# Want To Use Generic Props In Typescript Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I have created a component called Lists.tsx to understand generic prop types

```
import { ReactNode } from "react"

type ListProps<T> = {
   items: T[]
   onClick: (value: T) => void
}

const Lists = <T extends {}> ({ items, onClick }: ListProps<T>) => {

   return (
      <div>
         <h2>List of Items</h2>
         {
            items.map((item, index) => {
               return (
                  <div key={index} onClick={() => onClick(item)}>
                     {item}
                  </div>
               )
            })
         }
      </div>
   )
}

export default Lists
```

Invoking Lists.tsx in App.tsx for different prop types for items prop

```
<Lists items={['A', 'B', 'C', 1]} onClick={(item) => console.log(item)} />

<Lists items= {[{first: 'Haseeb',last: 'Irfan'}]} onClick={(item) => console.log(item)} />
```

I am getting a typescript error on rendering `{item}`

The error is:

```
type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ReactPortal'.
      Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, children, type, propsts(2322)
```

I have tried `{item as ReactNode}` which satisfies the compiler but here is a runtime error now

```
ERROR
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {first, last}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

How can I resolve this so I can use array of strings, numbers, and objects as a prop type to use the component generically?

Comment: You can't render objects directly as a React node. You would have to convert it to another structure. This can't be solved by fixing the typing issue.

Comment: React will fire a runtime error when you try to do so